# Cant send my tezos due to proto.006-PsCARTHA.contract.cannot_pay_storage_fee

Tags: ledger, error, fees

[image]

I tried several times by reducing the amont for sending meaning instead of 1.4, 1.3. and 1 xtz same error!

Answer (score 2):

When you send a transaction to an empty address you have to pay `0.257 tez` allocation fee and in your case that caused a problem:

1. At the block `930365` [your balance was `1.336011 tez`](https://mainnet.tezos.org.ua/chains/main/blocks/930365/context/contracts/tz1hF2rgmnJVo6MKxuVWdPV89HpUu9CHSCti).
2. At the block `930366` you [tried to send a transaction](https://tzkt.io/onvkNJs2vYt9czdqX7TJVKza6V9t8UtSnffFGSXWRsY8pKBuH8v) with amount `1.1 tez`, baker fee `0.015913 tez` and allocation fee `0.257 tez` - it's `1.372913‬ tez` in total.

As you can see, you tried to spend more than you had.

---

By the way, I suggest you use [TzKT Explorer](https://tzkt.io/) with its detailed error messages:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Which client are you using to send the transaction? In the failing [transaction](https://tzstats.com/onvkNJs2vYt9czdqX7TJVKza6V9t8UtSnffFGSXWRsY8pKBuH8v) you did not include the origination burn. However it seems that in a subsequent [transaction](https://tzstats.com/onnG5LSfXTJ6ub4ZaP37YFDShALFb6GKso3uXFXpg33MziD2rxb) you did include the origination burn and that it worked.